# Error for export at godot 4

Tags: export, godot-4

I tried this code in GDScript, in Godot 4:

```
export (int) var width;

export (int) var height;
```

And at Metadata add width and height but these below don't show and have an error.

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: What is the exact error message you see?

Answer (score 3):

That syntax would work in Godot 3.x.

Let us break it down first. This is a variant variable called `width`:

```
# Godot 3.x or Godot 4.x
var width
```

We can add an optional `;` at the end. The `;` separates multiple statements on the same line. Since we are not adding more statements to the line, this is the same thing as before:

```
# Godot 3.x or Godot 4.x
var width;
```

Now, to export the variable (so it is available in the inspector), in Godot 3.x you did this:

```
# Godot 3.x
export (int) var width;
```

Here the variable is being exported as an `int`. However, the variable is still a variant. It could have values that are not `int` if you set them from code. But it will show as an `int` in the inspector.

We need to fix that. Because in Godot 4.x, you don't do that. In fact, we could have fixed that in Godot 3.x, it looked like this:

```
# Godot 3.x
export var width:int
```

Now the variable is an `int`, and we don't need to tell it to export it as an `int`, because exporting an `int` as an `int` is the default (yes, there is another option: exporting at as an Enum).

*Yes, Godot 3.x had typed variables. It is not a type hint.*

And now, this is how that looks like in Godot 4.x:

```
# Godot 4.x
@export var width:int
```

That is because `export` is no longer a keyword, but an annotation instead. Annotations are a new language feature in GDScript 2.0 (the one that comes with Godot 4.x), and they all start with `@`.

Comment: Hi. thank you for